# Android zipalign Error - Verification FAILED

Tags: android, compression, google-play

I am trying to zipalign my App buti always get the error: "Verification FAILED". There are no more information, only some *.png files with (BAD - 1) but i dont know what the this means.

Can someone tell me what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was, that we singed the App automatically but with the wrong sigalg!

Android caution:

> Caution: As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

We used RSA incase of MD5withRSA